# DB server and NFS mount on same Solaris server

Tags: solaris

The scnerio goes like this.
I have a Physical server which have to have two work to do, 1) Act as a DB server and 2) NFS mount has to be created on it.
The OS is Solaris 10, now, Can i achieve the same without having any difficulty and backup and DR aspect should also be taken care of.

I know this is widely asked question but expert people can give a good response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have both a database and NFS server running on the same machine.

If your question is about locally exporting a NFS share so the same machine can mount it, that's a bit insane. You should access your files locally without the complexity introduced by making your operations go through the NFS layer.